# QML: Hide ToolTip when outside of ScrollView

Tags: qml

In the example code, ToolTip text gets above header and footer. Is there a way to hide ToolTip when it is outside of ScrollView?

The idea is to have TextInputs and show tooltip when it have focus. Here I have replaced TextInput with Buttons for simplification.

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: headerRect
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 150
            color: "blue"
            z: 1
        }

        ScrollView {
            id: scrollview
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            ListView{
                id: listview

                model: {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}
                spacing: 1
                delegate: Button {
                   text: "Button"
                   ToolTip{
                       visible: parent.focus? true : false
                       text: "tooltip text"
                   }
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: footerRect
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 150
            color: "blue"
            z: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use hovered replace focurse

```
ToolTip{
    visible: parent.hovered ? true : false
    text: "tooltip text"
}
```